# How to tranfer Wordpress running on Amazon EC2+RDS to another Amazon account?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've a wordpress blog running on Amazon EC2 (the database is on RDS). I want to transfer it to a new Amazon account. I've two doubts:

1. Do I have to completely recreate the environment from scratch?
2. How would I restore Wordpress?

I'm aware that the longer route would be to create the environment again, take WP backup and then import it. But what would be the smarter way to do the same thing?

Please guide. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to move your EC2 instance copy** -

1 : Make your AMI public.

2 : Share your AMI with specific user.

Details http://aws.amazon.com/articles/530

**Steps to move your RDS database copy**

If you dont have the RDS instance public accesible :

- Create an EC2 instance and configure the databases.
- Copy data from RDS to EC2
- Launch RDS instance in 2nd account EC2 instance, and configure the database access permissions.
- Copy database from EC2 to the 2nd account RDS.

If you have the RDS public accesible :

- Create a new RDS instance in the new aws account where you want to move your DB.
- Give the PC network access for both RDS instance, and copy from one db to another.

Comment: @LittleLebowski You will have to dump and import your database into the new RDS instance.

Comment: So from what I understand:

1. Make my AMI public and share it with the other account.

2. Take a complete backup of WP files and folders (Is this step necessary? Will the AMI already have it?)

3. Take a SQL dump of the DB and then import it in the new account RDS

4. Make changes in the WP config files to point to the correct RDS.

5. Make the AMI private again.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: @LittleLebowski - Please see the edit for RDS transfer logic.